# I Cant select from spinner

Tags: android, android-spinner

after i click on the item in the spinner  nothing selected.

```
    public  void getSpinnerItems(){


    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,ToolsUtils.STOP_CODE_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {


                    try {


                        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                        JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject();
                        for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++) {
                             jsonObject=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            String s=jsonObject.getString("stopDesc");
                            eque_array.add(s);
                        }


                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    //displaying the error in toast if occurrs
                    error.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
```

//creating a request queue
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

//adding the string request to request queue
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

//fill the spinner

```
    ArrayAdapter<String> arr=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,eque_array);
    spinner.setAdapter(arr);
}
```

I use this listener to return the selected item

```
 spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

         String   selected_item =spinner.getItemAtPosition( position).toString();
            ((TextView) view).setTextColor(Color.RED);
           validator.setText(spinner);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            stop_code="nothing" ;
            validator.setText(spinner );
        }
    });
```

I click on the itme but it not return any thing.

Comment: where do you set the adapter? onCreate?

Comment: same problem for `String   selected_item =spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();` ??

Comment: yes I try this and nothing change :(

Comment: it work true when i add the item to the List  eque_array but when i use json data it don't work

Comment: are you not able to see data selected in the UI , means in the validator textView?

Comment: no I put  the adapter in the method  getSpinnerItems() and i call it in onCreate

Comment: I can see the data in the UI but after click nothing change

Comment: Is there another way to display items in drop down list or dialog??

Answer (score 1):

You can try this
first create spinner in your layout xml like

```
                    <Spinner
                        android:id="@+id/spinner"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="48dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/border"
                        android:dropDownVerticalOffset="50dp"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:padding="3dp"
                        android:prompt="@string/country_prompt"
                        android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />

create a spinner_items file in layout folder like  

<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerItemStyle"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:background="@drawable/spinner_item_divider"
    android:textAlignment="inherit"/>
```

and call this method from after getting response and do changes according to your requirement

```
private void intializeAdapter(ArrayList<String>arrList) {

        final ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new 
         ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.spinner_items, arrList) {
            @Override
            public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
                if (position == 0) {
                    return false;
                } else {

                    return true;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View view = super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
                 tv = (TextView) view;
                TextView tv1 = (TextView) view;
                if (position == 0) {
                    // Set the hint text color gray
                    tv.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);

                } else {
                    tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

                   // tv.setText(numberValue);


                    // tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                }
                return view;
            }
        };
        spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_items);
        spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String selectedItemText = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                if (position > 0) {
                    result = selectedItemText;
                    textView=(TextView) view;
                    numberValue=selectedItemText;
                    if(numberValue.equals("other")){
                         openAlertDialog();
                    }else if(numberValue.equals("Andet")){
                        openAlertDialog();
                    }

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: my app can't find this method openAlertDialog();

Comment: android:background="@drawable/spinner_item_divider"

Comment: can i change this??android:background="@drawable/spinner_item_divider"

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/white"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:bottom="1dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/gray0"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>

Comment: inside drawable folder

Comment: the problem doesn't solve .my problem not in the show in UI.it's that when I click on any item nothing change like if you don't use the spinner

Comment: Is there another way to display items in drop down list or dialog??

Comment: plz let me know what exactly you wants we could not understand what is your problem

Comment: in onitemsekected there is a String selectedItemText = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position); selectedItemText will be your item value and you can use it